# Insert values from list into table (Python, sqlite3)

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have this simple code which I can't make work.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db\\books')
c = conn.cursor()

col = []

title = input('title')
text = input('text')
tags = input('tags')

col.append(title)
col.append(text)
col.append(tags)

c.executescript("INSERT INTO books (title,text,tags) "
                "VALUES (col[0],col[1],col[2])")
```

The db code (connection and normal insert) works but the problem rise when I want to do what you see above.

The goal I would like to achieve is to let the user insert the data into db (all strings). I don't know if this is the right way to do this...

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to change your last line to:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO books (title,text,tags) VALUES (?,?,?)", (col[0], col[1], col[2]))
```

And then commit and close the connection if you're done making changes:

```
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: `c.execute()` definitely takes two arguments, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). Adrian Tam's example looks good to me too. Are you sure you're calling the correct function?

Comment: In fact, the error comes out using `c.executescript()`. Using `c.execute` shows no error but it don't do anything...

Comment: Understood the error...I didn't copied conn.commit(). Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
c.executescript("INSERT INTO books (title,text,tags) "
                "VALUES (col[0],col[1],col[2])")
```

Is not a valid SQL. Now since `c` is defined as a cursor, you can run `execute` from it directly instead of `executescript`, which the latter is suppose to create a cursor from a connection and execute a SQL. Just replace that line with the following should work:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO books (title,text,tags) "
          "VALUES (?,?,?)", col)
```

The SQL above uses a "qmark style" placeholder, which takes actual value from the parameter list that follows it.

Comment: TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)